# How to add new elements to a SOAP XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap

I have a SOAP XML file name "LogEvents.xml" that I want to add/remove elements from it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" >
  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:lle="http://www.examplee.org/logevents" >

  <Event>
    <eventid>ID-1</eventid>
    <title>title1</title>
    <description>desc1</description>
    <location>
      <lat>1.357207</lat>
      <long>103.944880</long>
      <address>address1</address>
    </location>
    <datetimestamp>datetime1</datetimestamp>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <eventid>ID-2</eventid>
    <title>title2</title>
    <description>desc2</description>
    <location>
      <lat>1.304121</lat>
      <long>103.831950</long>
      <address>addres2</address>
    </location>
    <datetimestamp>datetime2</datetimestamp>
  </Event>
    
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Below shows the code that I have tried but failed using Visual Studio.

```
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\LogEvents.xml");
                     

xDoc1.Element("SOAP-ENV").Add(new XElement("Event", new XElement("eventid", "strEventID"),
                                                    new XElement("title", "title2"),
                                                    new XElement("description", "desc3"),
                                                    new XElement("location", new XElement("lat", "lat3"),
                                                                             new XElement("long", "long3"),
                                                                             new XElement("address", "addresses3")),
                                                    new XElement("datetimestamp", "DateTime3")));
```

I have tried to remove the SOAP envelope in the XML file and replace it with "Events" and edit the C# code accordingly and it works as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Changed to Events-->
<Events>
  <Event>
    <eventid>ID-1</eventid>
    <title>title1</title>
    <description>desc1</description>
    <location>
      <lat>1.357207</lat>
      <long>103.944880</long>
      <address>address1Edge</address>
    </location>
    <datetimestamp>datetime1</datetimestamp>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <eventid>ID-2</eventid>
    <title>title2</title>
    <description>desc2</description>
    <location>
      <lat>1.304121</lat>
      <long>103.831950</long>
      <address>addres2</address>
    </location>
    <datetimestamp>datetime2</datetimestamp>
<!--Changed to Events-->
  </Event>
<Events>
```

```
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\LogEvents.xml");
                     
// Changed SOAP-ENV to Events
xDoc1.Element("Events").Add(new XElement("Event", new XElement("eventid", "ID-3"),
                                                    new XElement("title", "title3"),
                                                    new XElement("description", "desc3"),
                                                    new XElement("location", new XElement("lat", "lat3"),
                                                                             new XElement("long", "long3"),
                                                                             new XElement("address", "addresses3")),
                                                    new XElement("datetimestamp", "DateTime3")));
```

Is there any method to ignore the SOAP envelope, or a way to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Root.  You can always get the default namespace from the root when needed.

```
           XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement soap = xDoc1.Root;
            XNamespace ns = soap.GetDefaultNamespace();

            soap.Add(new XElement("Event", new XElement("eventid", "strEventID"),
                                                    new XElement("title", "title2"),
                                                    new XElement("description", "desc3"),
                                                    new XElement("location", new XElement("lat", "lat3"),
                                                                             new XElement("long", "long3"),
                                                                             new XElement("address", "addresses3")),
                                                    new XElement("datetimestamp", "DateTime3")));
```